# Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:name"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml to override

Tags: flutter, android-manifest

I got an error

```
Attribute application@theme value=(@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar) from [:flutter_barcode_scanner] AndroidManifest.xml:17:9-59
    is also present at [:stripe_payment] AndroidManifest.xml:9:18-74 value=(@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:theme"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:22:5-109:19 to override.
```

When i try to add the `tools:replace="android:theme"` to `<application>` but it didn’t fixed the error

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this error by the following steps

- Select any dart file and then Go Tools > Flutter > Opening for editing Android Studio
- Now wait to complete it all the process (Grande, indexing etc)
- Select Android like below in image
- [image]
- Find `flutter_barcode_scanner` and open `manifests/AndroidManifest.xml`
- add `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` to `AndroidManifest.xml` header
- Add `tools:replace="android:theme"` to the `<application ...`
  like below code

  ```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <application
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <activity android:name="com.amolg.flutterbarcodescanner.BarcodeCaptureActivity" />
    </application>
  ```
- This all above steps repeat for  `stripe_payment`.